# Simple calculator in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I am building a simple calculator as a learning exercise and I have stumbled - I get the user input for the first number, but it fails to store the int for the second input - do I need to create objects? I assume this is an obvious problem...

```
//Simple calculator to work out the sum of two numbers (using addition)

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Enter the first int: \n";
    int input1 = std::cin.get();

    cout << "Enter the second int: \n";
    int input2 = std::cin.get();


    cout << "The sum of these numbers is: " << input1 + input2;
    cout << "\n";


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cin.get()` only retrieves one character of input. Why not use

```
int input1, input2;
cout << "Enter the first int: \n";
cin >> input1;
cout << "Enter the second int: \n";
cin >> input2;
```

Using `std::cin` this way (with `operator>>`) also takes care of any surplus newline or space characters a user entered.